# C# No overload for method matches delegate Action ForEach

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have an conundrum I can't quite figure out and I'm quite sure it's just me misunderstanding something.

I have the following extension method:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var number in enumeration)
    {
        action?.Invoke(number);
    }
}
```

That extension method allows me to do the following:

```
var curiousNumbers = new List<BigInteger>();
// some code to fill curiousNumbers
curiousNumbers.ForEach(x => DebugLog(x));  

protected static void DebugLog(object logmessage)
{
    Logger.Log(logmessage.ToString());
}
```

However when I try to do this syntax:

```
curiousNumbers.ForEach(DebugLog);
```

I am getting a compile error with the following:
No overload for 'BaseProblem.DebugLog(object)' matches delegate 'Action<>BigInteger<>'

Now If I introduce a new DebugLog Method with an explicit type of BigInteger everything compiles and runs:

```
protected static void DebugLog(BigInteger logmessage)
{
    Logger.Log(logmessage.ToString());
}
```

This works but what if I have a list of Ints? I'd have to add another DebugLog method for every explicit type. Is there a way I can re-write the ForEach extension method or DebugLog method that both handles all types and allows for the curiousNumbers.ForEach(DebugLog) syntax?

Comment: You could read the rules on how C# works out which method is used when overloading in the C# specification: in the end this is down to the rules above conversions. Just remember when you pass `DebugLog` the compiler actually constructs an instance of the `Action<T>` delegate: this is not a simple one step conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compile error you are getting is due to the method `DebugLog` having a parameter of type `object`, but the sequence you are passing contains elements of type `BigInteger`. Which type should the generic type `T` of `ForEach<T>` evaluate to? It can't be both at the same time. Make the `DebugLog` method generic as well to solve your problem:

```
protetected static void DebugLog<T>(T message)
{
    Logger.Log(message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I assumed a parameter of  object was sufficient but turning it generic resolved the method immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the prototype:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
```

The `T` is for both the action and the input enumerable and that's why you have the additional constraint.

Since you are iterating a T object, you will probably want to run a T action.

You alternatives are:

1.Create a T1,T2 ForEach:

```
public static void ForEach<T1,T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> enumeration, Action<T2> action)
```

2.Create a generic implementation of `DebugLog` instead of passing a object as a parameter.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that #2 actually resolves the problem without doing #1